# Calling web service from WinJS.xhr - format

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, xmlhttprequest

I need to call a SharePoint web service called http://myfulldomain.com/_vti_bin/webpartpages.asmx

The method I want to call is called GetWebPart and it accepts 3 parameters: pageurl, storagekey, storage.

I am not sure how I specify the URI to call/how to specify the parameters, do I use the data: object?

So far I have:

```
var dashboardURL = "http://myfulldomain.com/_vti_bin/webpartpages.asmx/GetWebPart";
WinJS.xhr({ url: dashboardURL })
    .done(function complete(result) {
        q("#sharepointresponse").innerText = "Downloaded";
    },
    function error(result) {
        q("#sharepointresponse").innerText = "Error: " + result.statusText;
    });
```

In short how do I call a specific method of a web service and how do I specify parameters?

Thanks,
Andrew